# matching subsequent space separated numbers as different tokens

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In a flat file,for which i'm trying to write a parser, there is a line like this:

```
//TN PN RO
0 5 3
```

TN,PN and RO are the parameter names (i have added here the line starting with "//" for better understanding. The actual file does not have it).

The ranges for each of these parameters are different. 
TN can be 0 or 1, PN 0-7 and RO 0-3.

I understand why the following grammar does not work (0 and 1 matched by all lexer rules, 2 and 3 are matched by the PN and RO rules) but is there a way to achieve what i'm trying to do here.

```
grammar PARAM;

parameters: TN PN RO;

TN: [0-1];
RN: [0-7];
RO: [0-3];

WS : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip ;
```

I like to match these overlapping numbers as different tokens. Otherwise i have to change my grammar to this and then in the the Java side check the ranges manually.

```
grammar PARAM;

parameters: DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;

DIGIT: [0-7];

WS : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the lexer does not know the context / number position on line (unless hacked by some custom code), it does not know whether to match 0 as TN, RN or RO. The right place to make this distinction is the parser.

You could do this to avoid checking the ranges in Java (although I would personally check them in Java rather than do this):

```
parameters: tn_param rn_param ro_param;

tn_param: TN_DIGIT;
rn_param: TN_DIGIT | RO_DIGIT | RN_DIGIT;
ro_param: TN_DIGIT | RO_DIGIT;

TN_DIGIT: [0-1];
RO_DIGIT: [2-3];
RN_DIGIT: [4-7];
```